# How to properly write Regex validation in Firestore Security Rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to validate submitted data against Regex expressions in Firestore Security Rules. I've read through the documentation, but I'm still unsure how to write them.

I read through the Regex documentation here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/regex , but it doesn't really show how to use it in Firestore. I tried using an 'allow validate' rule and copy/pasted a regex expression from the docs, but I'm getting all kinds of errors.

Here's what I tried:

[image: link]

Do I need to put it in a format like this? (From the docs) `allow create: if !("ranking" in request.resource.data)`? If so, how do I use a regex expression with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to start a regex with `/`.  That's not going to work - it's not like perl.  Slash starts a path object.  Might want to check the API documentation on this.  You should just be passing a plain string to `matches()` that contains the regex to match.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#matches

Comment: Wait, is 'allow validate' even a valid part of the rules? I'm simulating rules and it's not an option to select.

Comment: It's syntactically valid, but it will have no effect, as there is nothing hooked up to that method.  The error starts with the slash that starts the regex.